# GO routines in a loop - function call

Tags: go

**Description of the problem**

I want to send a concurrent call to each iteration on my *for loop*.

**Current Code**

This program mostly try's to find a valid directory on the server

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var site string
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        site = os.Args[1]
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Need the host. Example > http://www.google.com/")
        fmt.Println("wfuzz http://www.google.com/ wordlist.txt")
        site = "http://www.google.com"
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    f, err := os.Open(os.Args[2])

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error opening file!", err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        a := site + scanner.Text()
        get_page(a)
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
    }

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    fmt.Println("done")

}

func get_page(site string) string {
    a := "\n"
    res, err := http.Get(site)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    if res.StatusCode != 404 {
        fmt.Println("Page Found!! +::", site, " ::+", res.StatusCode)
    }
    return a
}
```

**Goal to Achieve**

What I want to achieve is mostly send on my for loop concurrent calls that way i would speed up the process and would be the end goal for the current program.

Answer (score 3):

Using a combination of the Go standard libraries `sync.WaitGroup` and channels, you can accomplish this without having to explicitly keep track of the number of words in the file you wish to read from.

Modify your `get_page` (side note: it is not idiomatic go to user underscores in func names -> https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names ) func to accept an additional channel and wait group and you could do something like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    
    //your previous code for getting the command line arguments from os.Args, then...

    //create a WaitGroup
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)

    //create a channel that you can write your results too
    resultChan := make(chan string)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        //increment the waitgroup
        wg.Add(1)
        a := site + scanner.Text()
        //call the getPage with the http target, with the result chan, and the waitgroup
        go getPage(a, resultChan, wg)
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
        //if there is an error, close the result chan so progam can exit (for more robust cancellation of potential currently running go routines, take a look at https://blog.golang.org/pipelines)
        close(resultChan)
    }

    //start another go routine to wait for all concurrent calls to get_page to complete, then close the result channel
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(resultChan)
    }()

    for result := range resultChan {
        //deal with the result in some way
        fmt.Println(result)
    }

    fmt.Println("done")
}

//side note - it is not idiomatic go to use underscores in func name
func getPage(site string, ch chan<- string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    //decrement waitgroup when operation completes
    defer wg.Done()

    res, err := http.Get(site)
    if err != nil {
        ch <- fmt.Sprintf("error: %s", err)
        return
    }
    if res.StatusCode != 404 {
        ch <- fmt.Sprintf("Page Found!! +:: %s ::+ %d", site, res.StatusCode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> sync.WaitGroup

The only problem is that you have how many concurrent calls you are gonna do.

example

if the wordlist.txt contents this

```
admin.php 
admin
administrator
administrator
```

you know that you will make 4 concurrent calls

if the content is

```
admin.php
admin/
administrator/
administrator/
administrator/
administrator/
```

you know you will make 6 concurrent calls.

The code below was make with a file of 3 words

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"

      "bufio"
   "net/http"
    "os"
)


func main(){



    var site string
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        site = os.Args[1]
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Need the host. Example > http://www.google.com/")
        fmt.Println("wfuzz http://www.google.com/ wordlist.txt")
        site = "http://www.google.com"
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    f, err := os.Open(os.Args[2])

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error opening file!", err)
    }

     wg.Add(3) // TODO check the number of words in the file 


     scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
     for scanner.Scan() {

        a := site + scanner.Text()
        go get_page(a,&wg)

    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
    }


   wg.Wait()
   fmt.Println("done")

}



func get_page(site string,wg *sync.WaitGroup)  string{
    a := "\n"

    defer wg.Done()

    res, err := http.Get(site)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }

    if res.StatusCode != 404 {
        fmt.Println("Page Found!! +::", site, " ::+", res.StatusCode)
    }
    return a

}
```

Comment: Yep got a problem with the concurrency that I didn't though before ... when we have too many connections to a website the webserver sometimes refuses more than a certain amount of connections, or the firewall even that is timing out the connections giving false information about available resources in the server but thank you for your code works in my Lab :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `go get_page(a)` which start a goroutine for each word on the wordlist, to set maximum concurrent calls use work pool. (https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools)

Comment: the problem is if i use go get_page(a) whats is going to happen is my main function is going to end before the loop in other words the output with only go get_page(a) is zero.

Comment: you can solve that by using channels, please check out the given example. (The part with "Finally we collect all the results of the work." description waits until all workers are done)